# Else statement triggers twice in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, if-statement, segue

I've been trying to register a user to Firebase and while doing that I'm checking if there is an error. If error occurs, then my code block pops up a UIalertcontroller and prints "error" once So far it works fine.

When there is no error then it should do a segue and print "segue done". But While it has no error the code triggers segue twice and prints "segue done" twice. Why this happens?

```
@IBAction func registerButton(_ sender: Any) {
    firestoreManager.registerUser(mail: mailField.text!, fullName: fullNameField.text!, username: usernameField.text!, password: passwordField.text!, instruments: instrumentArray, registerUserError: { [self] (canRegister) in
        if canRegister == false {
            print("registeruserfail")
                        
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: firestoreManager.errorString, preferredStyle: .alert)
            self.present(alert, animated: false) {
                alert.message = firestoreManager.errorString
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
                print("error")
            }
        }
        else { // this statement triggers twice
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMainPage", sender: self)
            print("segue done")
            return
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your `registerButton` is not called twice ?

Comment: I suppose not. Because when there is error print("error") and print("registeruserfail") triggers only once

Comment: Could you please check if your method is not called twice ? Just put a breakpoint or a print statement before the `if canRegister == false`

Comment: I've tried what you said. Put a print statement right under registerButton but it did print for once

Comment: Kind of weird, just an other thought: are you sure you are not making the same segue and printing the same error somewhere else in your code ? The code can't be called twice if the print statement before was not called twice neither.

Comment: The code could be called any number of times, if the firestoreManager calls the registerUserError closure multiple times.

Comment: @artikes123 put a print statement inside the closure body, so it would also print twice if `registerUserError` is called twice

Comment: While seeming strange, the most straightforward answer is firebase is calling the closure twice.  Put a breakpoint or print at the start of the closure so you can see whenever it's being called to rule this out.

Comment: As you guys all said, the closure triggers twice. When I put a print("closure") statement right inside the closure, what I get in terminal when I 've successfully done segue is 'closure
segue done
closure
segue done' what should I do to solve that problem?